# Nil object when you didn't expect it for contact form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm trying to add a contact form for my Rails 3.1.3 application using [this tutorial](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/). However at the end when I try to load my contact page, I get the error:

*You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]*

It says it occurs on line 1 of this code block on the new.html.haml page:

```
  = form_for @message, :url => { :action=>"new", :controller=>"contact"} do |form|
    %fieldset.fields
      .field
        = form.label :name
        = form.text_field :name
      .field
        = form.label :email
        = form.text_field :email
      .field
        = form.label :body
        = form.text_area :body
    %fieldset.actions
      = form.submit "Send"
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @message = Message.new
    end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Model looks like this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :body

  validates :name, :email, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

Why would I be getting that error and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: is your haml indention correctly typed in above? It looks like `%fieldset.fields` is not a child of `form_for`

Comment: Yes, that was just a copy/paste error. Everything is indented properly as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

do you add the routes as mention in the tutorial ?

```
match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get
match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post
```

Beside you can just use in ur form as

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
```

Comment: Yes, I have this: match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get
  match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post. I tried doing contact_path for the url but it gave me the same error. contact_path wasn't there when I did rake routes so I took it out to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using separate forms for new and edit actions, you can this in new.html.haml

```
 = form_for :message, :url => { :action=>"new", :controller=>"contact"} do |form|
```

or

```
= form_for :message, @message, :url => { :action=>"new", :controller=>"contact"} do |form|
```

Comment: Okay I tried that (there's no edit), I get the same error but now on line 5 (form text field name). Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Went through some rails documentation. They suggest using 
   = form_for :message, @message :url => { :action=>"new", :controller=>"contact"} do |form|

Comment: That's giving me "syntax error, unexpected ':'," for the first line. Is there supposed to be something between @message and :url? I searched the rails documentation and couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Comma was missing.